# How to use bigquery pagination with golang library

Tags: go, google-bigquery

I have read the documentation on pagination for BigQuery in Golang, but I need more details and an actual example to follow. Can someone provide a code snippet that shows how to correctly read a large number of rows with pagination in Golang using the BigQuery API?

```golang
func read(ctx context.Context, client *bigquery.Client) error {
    clientQuery := client.Query("select * from very_big_table")
    readJob, err := clientQuery.Run(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    it, err := readJob.Read(ctx)

    // ?? how to use here pagination ??
}
```

I have looked at the comments within the BigQuery code, but they are not reliable enough for me to implement. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: According to https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/paging-results#iterate_through_client_libraries_results, the client libs already handle the low-level details of API pagination, so you can just use the iterator API even when loading large amt of data. 
Example iterating with go sdk: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/paging-results#bigquery_browse_table-go

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by @wijayaerick cloud client lib can handle api pagination and can provide iterator-like experience. According to the documentation, The client library for Go automatically paginates by default.

This is the pagination example for GO:

```
import (
        "context"
        "fmt"
        "io"

        "cloud.google.com/go/bigquery"
        "google.golang.org/api/iterator"
)

func browseTable(w io.Writer, projectID, datasetID, tableID string) error {
        // projectID := "my-project-id"
        // datasetID := "mydataset"
        // tableID := "mytable"
        ctx := context.Background()
        client, err := bigquery.NewClient(ctx, projectID)
        if err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("bigquery.NewClient: %v", err)
        }
        defer client.Close()

        table := client.Dataset(datasetID).Table(tableID)
        it := table.Read(ctx)
        for {
                var row []bigquery.Value
                err := it.Next(&row)
                if err == iterator.Done {
                        break
                }
                if err != nil {
                        return err
                }
                fmt.Fprintln(w, row)
        }
        return nil
}
```

Comment: When iterating over large dataset/table Bigquery returning error 403 responseTooLarge. So their pagination implementation isn't good enough, hence I need to do it on my own.